# Cannot edit my wordpress footer background color

Tags: wordpress, local, footer, custom-wordpress-pages, wpbakery

I've been trying to edit my footer background color. If I go into my edit page > footer options I see these color options but still do not work after I adjust the background color. Any other idea how I can adjust the background color of my footer? I've looked at theme options, customize, WP Bakery page builder and can't seem to find it. The only color option that works is when I adjust the Footer Heading Color [image: color options] thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add custom CSS to your site.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

You have to find your footer class name. After that, you can add a footer heading color. For example:

```
.your-footer-heading-class-name{
    color: red;
 }
```

If don't work the code you can try this:

```
.your-footer-heading-class-name{
    color: red !important;
 }
```